# I'm getting error "Pokemon.cpp:11:18: error: cannot call member function ‘int Dice::roll()’ without object"

Tags: c++

### Pokemon fight simulator

I'm working on building a simple fight simulator. It will be able to take the user inputs for HP, attack lv, and defense lv.

```
Pokemon::Pokemon() {
healthPoints = attackL = defL=0;
    std::string Pname= "";
    d20=Dice(20);
    d6=Dice(6);
```

I have 4 files Pokemon.h, Pokemon.cpp, Dice.h, Dice.cpp. The Pokemon header file contains

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Dice.h"


class Pokemon {

    private:
        int healthPoints, attackL, defL;
        #include <iostream>
std::string Pname;
        Dice d20;
        Dice d6;

    public:
        Pokemon();
        bool attack(Pokemon& opponent);
        void userBuild();
} ;
```

Pokemon.cpp uses the Pokemon class to "*build*" the user's pokemon. The part where I'm stuck is when trying to use

```
Pokemon::bool attack(){
d20=Dice.roll()

}
```

I get an error "*Pokemon.cpp:13:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘bool’*"

This are the instructions on what 'bool attack' should do

> bool attack(Pokemon& opponent)
>
> > use the d20 to roll random values for and attackBonus and a defenseBonus
> >     if the attackLevel+attackBonus of the attacker is greater than the the >>defenseLevel+defenseBonus of the defender, then roll for damage. Otherwise the attack misses
> >     if the attack lands, roll three d6's, add them up, and that is the damage
> >     display all attack information as reflected in the sample runs
> >     return true only if the opponent died because of the attack, otherwise returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for implementing a member function is

```
bool Pokemon::attack(Pokemon& opponent){
...
}
```

Comment: I change that and now it returns the error

>Pokemon.cpp:13:6: error: prototype for ‘bool Pokemon::attack()’ does not match any in class ‘Pokemon’
 bool Pokemon::attack(){
      ^
Pokemon.h:17:8: error: candidate is: bool Pokemon::attack(Pokemon&)
   bool attack(Pokemon& opponent);
        ^
Compilation failed.

Comment: @rubito Because the declaration in the header file declares a parameter.

Comment: @Radiodef could you please explain/expand? Would 'bool Pokemon::attack(Pokemon & opponent){
} work?

Comment: Yeah that works! Thanks @Radiodef. Could you guys point me in the right direction as to how to use the random Dice::roll class to assign a random value to the dice in order to assign an attack bonus?

Comment: @rubito: Search the web for "c++ random dice"